# FLUTTER Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'CioInternalCommon'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, mobile

I'm trying to run flutter on my device (iphone 12 pro) with `flutter run` command and show me that error.

[image]

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'CioInternalCommon'
/Users/pasquale.delucia/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/customer_io-1.3.1/ios/Classes/SwiftCustomerIoPlugin.swift:3:7



Error launching application on iPhone di Pasquale.
```

I tryied to delete Pods and Podfile.lock and reainstall all, update cocoapods

Any ideas?

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on macOS 13.6.4 22G513 darwin-x64, locale it-IT)

Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)

VS Code (version 1.86.2)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem updating `CustomerIO/MessagingPushFCM` in podfile from 2.5.0 to 2.12.1

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  // this line
  pod 'CustomerIO/MessagingPushFCM', '~> 2.12.1'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```